# system of non-linear equations, complex substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have problems solving 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=2xy; \quad \frac{dy}{dt}=1+x^2-y^2.
\end{equation}

I can solve similiar system easily when I have
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dt}=2xy; \quad \frac{dx}{dt}=1+x^2-y^2,
\end{equation}
by introducing complex number $z=x+iy$, then $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}+i\frac{dy}{dt}$, by adding both equations I obtain $\frac{dz}{dt}=1+z^2$ which is trivial. However, in stated problem when trying to work with similiar substitution I end with wrong signs (which ruins furthers attempts) or I got equation type $i\frac{d\bar{z}}{dt}=1+z^2$, which also leads nowhere.

Any hints? I just can't see solution or any other way than complex substitution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think that there is no nice integral to solve this system

Answer (score 2):

The system is Hamiltonian: you can find a function $H(x,y)$ for which
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} &= \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}, \\
 \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} &= -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
Partial integration yields
\begin{equation}
 H(x,y) = x\left(y^2 - \frac{1}{3} x^2 -1\right).
\end{equation}
Ergo, this provides a nice integral to solve this system: the solutions are restricted to level sets of this Hamiltonian. Given such a level set $H(x,y) = E$, we can find for example $x(t)$ by solving the first order ODE
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = x^2 - \frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{E}{x}.
\end{equation}